# Change file encoding scheme in Python

Tags: python, file, python-unicode

I'm trying to open a file using latin-1 encoding in order to produce a file with a different encoding. I get a `NameError` stating that `unicode is not defined`. Here the piece of code I use to this:

```
sourceEncoding = "latin-1"
targetEncoding = "utf-8"
source = open(r'C:\Users\chsafouane\Desktop\saf.txt')
target = open(r'C:\Users\chsafouane\Desktop\saf2.txt', "w")

target.write(unicode(source.read(), sourceEncoding).encode(targetEncoding))
```

I'm not used at all to handling files so I don't know if there is a module I should import to use "unicode"

Comment: And, just to clarify, this is Python2 right? Because Python3 doesn't have a `unicode` function (strings are UTF8 by default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you see `unicode not defined` suggests that you're in Python3. Here's a code snippet that'll generate a latin1-encoded file, then does what you want to do, slurp the latin1-encoded file and spit out a UTF8-encoded file:

```
# Generate a latin1-encoded file

txt = u'U+00AxNBSP¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬SHY­®¯U+00Bx°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿U+00CxÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏU+00DxÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßU+00ExàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïU+00Fxðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ'

latin1 = txt.encode('latin1')

with open('example-latin1.txt', 'wb') as fid:
    fid.write(latin1)

# Read in the latin1 file

with open('example-latin1.txt', 'r', encoding='latin1') as fid:
    contents = fid.read()
assert contents == latin1.decode('latin1') # sanity check

# Spit out a UTF8-encoded file

with open('converted-utf8.txt', 'w') as fid:
    fid.write(contents)
```

If you want the output to be something other than UTF8, add an `encoding` argument to `open`, e.g.,

```
with open('converted-utf_32.txt', 'w', encoding='utf_32') as fid:
    fid.write(contents)
```

The docs have a [list of all supported codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).